# Data not inserting into database (SQL)

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have a form that gives the data to this File. I checked that the data comes in correctly and it does. I have connection to my database but the code isn't sending it to the database. Why isn't it working?

```
<?php 
        session_start();
        include_once("includes/db.php");


        if(isset($_POST['produkt']) && isset($_POST['größe']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['telefonnummer']) && isset($_POST['straße']) && isset($_POST['postleitzahl']) && isset($_POST['ort'])) {

            $produkt = $_POST['produkt'];
            $größe = $_POST['größe'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $telefonnummer = $_POST['telefonnummer'];
            $straße = $_POST['straße'];
            $postleitzahl = $_POST['postleitzahl'];
            $ort = $_POST['ort'];

            $sql_store = "INSERT into bestellungen (id, produkt, größe, name, telefonnummer, straße, postleitzahl, ort) VALUES (NULL, '$produkt', '$größe', '$name', '$telefonnummer', '$straße', '$postleitzahl', '$ort')";
            $sql = mysqli_query($db, $sql_store); 

        }

?>
```

Comment: without knowing your db.php and the bestellungen table, can't help you.

Comment: you have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: You can check mysqli_error to see if something went wrong

Comment: what are meaning "größe" or "straße" ? this words has utf-8 chars, maybe the issue came from this! don't use utf-8 chars for variables or tables name.

Comment: @aidinMC You are right! It works now! Thank you!